# Mask 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to apply mask on 2D numpy array. But it does not work correctly. Suppose I have

```
val(lat, lon)  ---> my 2D array (20, 30)


Mask_lat = np.ma.masked_array(lat, mask=latmask)  ---> masked lat (5,)


Mask_lon = np.ma.masked_array(lon, mask =lonmask)   ---> masked lon (8,)


Maks_val = np.ma.masked_array(val, mask=mask_lat_lon) ---> ?
```

I do not know how can I pass a correct `mask_lat_lon` to have masked `val (5,8)`. I would appreciate if one guides me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: my first idea is `lonmask&latmask` but I don't understand precisely what is `masked lat (5,)`

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. Could you give a concrete example showing your inputs and your desired output?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have two 1D arrays that represent y and x (lat and long) positions in a 2D array.  You want to mask a region based on the x/y position in the 2D array.

The key part to understand is that mask for a 2D array is also 2D.

For example, let's mask a single element of a 2D array:

```
import numpy as np

z = np.arange(20).reshape(5, 4)
mask = np.zeros(z.shape, dtype=bool)

mask[3, 2] = True

print z
print np.ma.masked_array(z, mask)
```

This yields:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15]
 [16 17 18 19]]

[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 -- 15]
 [16 17 18 19]]
```

In your case, you have two 1D x and y arrays that you need to create a 2D mask from.  For example:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-85, -78, 4)
y = np.linspace(32, 37, 5)
z = np.arange(20).reshape(5, 4)

xmask = (x > -82.6) & (x < -80)
ymask = (y > 33) & (y < 35.6)

print xmask
print ymask
```

We'd then need to combine them into a single 2D mask using broadcasting:

```
mask = xmask[np.newaxis, :] & ymask[:, np.newaxis]
```

Slicing with `newaxis` (or `None`, they're the same object) adds a new axis at that position, turning the 1D array into a 2D array.  It you have seen this before, it's useful to take a quick look at what `xmask[np.newaxis, :]` and `ymask[:, np.newaxis]` look like:

```
In [14]: xmask
Out[14]: array([False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)

In [15]: ymask
Out[15]: array([False,  True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [16]: xmask[np.newaxis, :]
Out[16]: array([[False, False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)

In [17]: ymask[:, np.newaxis]
Out[17]:
array([[False],
       [ True],
       [ True],
       [False],
       [False]], dtype=bool)
```

`mask` will then be (keep in mind that `True` elements are masked):

```
In [18]: xmask[np.newaxis, :] & ymask[:, np.newaxis]
Out[18]:
array([[False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Finally, we can create a 2D masked array from `z` based on this mask:

```
arr = np.masked_array(z, mask)
```

Which gives us our final result:

```
 [[ 0  1  2  3]
  [ 4  5 --  7]
  [ 8  9 -- 11]
  [12 13 14 15]
  [16 17 18 19]]
```

Comment: How would I change the logic so that when combining the two 1D masks to create the 2D mask, I mask anywhere either of the 1d masks were True. 

I have a very similar problem except I want to mask certain latitudes for all longitudes and certain longitudes for all latitudes. I have a 1D mask for latitudes and a 1D mask for longitudes.

Comment: @Will.Evo, to effectively clip the 2D array by two 1D masks, create `mask` as shown above, then `clipped_z = z[mask]`. This creates a 1D array that can then be converted to 2D with `clipped_z.reshape()`. Appropriate dimensions for reshaping can be obtained with `np.sum(xmask)` and `np.sum(ymask)`, which count the number of `True`.